# Creating Staff Directory Lookup Bot with LUIS Integration

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to setup LUIS to connect to my Azure WebApp Bot, I've been asked by my IT Director to test the bot on a "Simple" Staff Directory Lookup (hosted in Azure SQL VM's).

I was trying to configure LUIS to understand intents such as 'Who is in Hospitality', or 'Who is Joe Bloggs', but I'm struggling with how to do this.

Do I use entities for departments and people? Are there Pre-Built Intents for 'Greetings' and other commonly used intents?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions so I splitted my answer in 2 parts.

### Information detection (departement, names)

> [I want to] understand intents such as 'Who is in Hospitality', or 'Who is Joe
> Bloggs', but I'm struggling with how to do this.
>
> Do I use entities for departments and people?

***Department:***

If you have a limited and known list of departments, you can create an `Entity` which type will be `List`. It will process an `exact text match` on the items of this list (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intent-and-list-entity?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)).

If you don't have this list, use an `Entity` of type `Simple` (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-primary-and-secondary-data?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)) and label this entity in several (various) examples utterances that you provide. You can improve the detection by also adding a `Phrase list` in that case: it will help and is not processing an exact match in the list. And you should improve it over the time.

***People:***

For the people name detection, it will be a little bit more tricky. You can have a look to `Communication.ContactName` pre-built entity. If it's not working, create your own simple entity but I'm not sure that the results will be relevant.

### "Small talk" part

> Are there Pre-Built Intents for 'Greetings' and other commonly used
> intents?

There is no pre-built intents but there is a Lab Project called `Personality Chat` that is designed to manage such cases (in English only for the moment): https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-personality-chat

It is still in a lab version, so you should not use in production, but it is mostly open-source so you can give it a try and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your detailed response. I’ll try that when I go back to the office on Monday and let you know how it goes. Have a lovely weekend